# Screen recorder, issue when converting

Tags: java, screenshot, bufferedimage

I'm using BufferedImage to capture the screen images and then JpegImagesToMovie class to convert it to .mov, which I found online.

When I run the output file, it's at a super speed and not the original speed I recorded at. Can someone tell me what  need to do in order to get a real-time speed video?

Comment: What framerate are you capturing at?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to put in `Thread.sleep(1 / fps)`. Try to see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

You are possibly using the Oracle's example to convert images to `.mov`. The problem is that  the size of the file generated is very very large. You need to move to something more efficient and something with a little bit more abstraction. How about using `Xuggler` for making screen recorder ?

Now, to the question of making the movie slower. You need to reduce the frame rate. If you have need 60 fps, your 1 second will need to be shared by 60 frames. So for n fps, you need to have `(1/n)` sleep duration for your thread.